# Eclipse tomcat https configuration for localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, https, localhost

I am implementing https project.So i just tried ssl connection with tomcat 
 i created the key and certificates using the following commands from the following site.

http://mircwiki.rsna.org/index.php?title=Configuring_Tomcat_to_Support_SSL

```
genrsa –des3 –out tomcatkey.pem 2048

req –new –x509 –key tomcatkey.pem –out tomcatcert.pem –days 1095 -config "c:/openssl/tomcatkey.pem"
```

So i got the certificate and key from the openssl commands.(i used the key as "pratap")

i put these 2 files in tomcat folder.

i changed the connector element 8443

```
<Connector
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
           SSLCertificateFile="c:/tomcat7/tomcatcert.pem"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="c:/tomcat7/tomcatkey.pem"
           clientAuth="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1" SSLPassword="pratap" />
```

when i run `https://localhost:8443` it is running fine.

Now in eclipse i created the server of this and try to run from the eclipse

But it is showing the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
```

i did not use keystore command at any where.

could any body give some light on this..Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

You should read http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration.

BTW: "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" - this error means your keystore is crashed or you have used wrong password. If you use selfsigned cert remeber to create truststore.

Comment: Thanks for responding. There is no wrong with my files.. i guess eclipse is expecting with the form of jsse implementation...because there is no keystore in the procedure of apr approach..i guess we have to change to the apr environment to keystore (jsse) environment...any way when i tried with netbeans it is perfectly working...so i am sticking to netbeans...thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the keystore password into your connector configuration. Here is an example:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystorePass="qwerty"
            clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

If you want to use another keystore you need to create one:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore /home/user/.keystore2
```

and use it in your configuration:

```
<Connector 
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore2" keystorePass="qwerty"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```